# In-Memory-Cache in .Net application on iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, application-pool, asp.net-caching

I have implemented in-memory cache in .NET application without any expiration token. For some reason, the cache evicted by external proccess. At first I thought it happens because the Application Pool Recycling , thats true, and for that reason i set him to 6:00 am. Still, the cache evicted but not consistent.
thats one of the functions that releated to some controller.
Thanks in advance

```
namespace webApiService.Controllers {
public class DBStore {

  
    private const string presenceKey = "presence";
   
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<object, SemaphoreSlim> locks = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, SemaphoreSlim>();
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<object, SemaphoreSlim> fileLocks = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, SemaphoreSlim>();
    private readonly flexWHContext _context;
  
    bool fromCache = false;

    public DBStore(IMemoryCache memoryCache,flexWHContext context) {
        this.memoryCache = memoryCache;
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<List<Presence>> getPresence() {
        fromCache = false;
        if (!(fromCache = memoryCache.TryGetValue(presenceKey, out List<Presence> presence))) {
            SemaphoreSlim certLock = locks.GetOrAdd(presenceKey, k => new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1));
            await certLock.WaitAsync();
            try {
                if (!memoryCache.TryGetValue(presenceKey, out presence)) {
                    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\spdev\Desktop\WriteText.txt", "getPresence - not in cache  "+ DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine);;
                    presence = await _context.Presence.FromSqlRaw("SHP_SP_Presence").AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
                    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\spdev\Desktop\WriteText.txt", "getPresence - set  in cache" + Environment.NewLine);
                    //memoryCache.Set(presenceKey, presence, GetMemoryCacheEntryOptions());
                    memoryCache.Set(presenceKey, presence);

                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            } finally {
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\spdev\Desktop\WriteText.txt", "lock releaes" + Environment.NewLine+ Environment.NewLine);
                certLock.Release();
            }
        }
        if (fromCache) {
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\spdev\Desktop\WriteText.txt", "getPresence - bring from cache  " + DateTime.Now  + Environment.NewLine);
            
        }
        return presence;
    }
```

Comment: The source code of the MemoryCache shows the [compaction](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/88ecbab85beead9c7d9406ee2f3ea468b1d4cd1e/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/src/MemoryCache.cs#L366) is only triggered by the [SetEntry](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/88ecbab85beead9c7d9406ee2f3ea468b1d4cd1e/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/src/MemoryCache.cs#L215) when the capacity has [been exceeded](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/88ecbab85beead9c7d9406ee2f3ea468b1d4cd1e/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/src/MemoryCache.cs#L338).

Comment: In other words without interaction it should not do eviction automatically.

Comment: Could you please share under which identify your application pool is running? try to assign the iis_iusrs and iusr permission to the C:\Users\spdev\Desktop\WriteText.txt or move this file to somewhere else because iis user does not have enough permission to access the desktop file or folder. another thing is capture the dump and analysis that dump file https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump.